# How to remove schematic reference information in Altium Designer?

Tags: altium, pcb-fabrication

I want to remove the schematic reference information for a pcb component.
How is it possible?

To clarify I do not mean reference designators 'R1', 'R2', 'C7' and 'IC1' for example but part information such as 'OPAMP LM741' from the PCB file so somebody manufacturing a PCB does not have access to the parts list.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "schematic reference information".

Comment: Please see in the PCB environment, the properties of a component.

Comment: What do you mean by remove schematic reference information? 'R1', 'R2', etc?  I can't see why you would want to remove it entirely.  Do you just not want to show it on the silk screen?  This can be useful to save space when components are placed by machine.  If yes then all components or only some?

Comment: No, I don't want to remove designators ( R1, etc ).

Comment: In the "Schematic Reference Information" in component properties in PCB file, there is a Library Ref parameter which links to the schematic ( for Example a LM741 opamp ). I want to remove this parameter in the PCB file.

Comment: The reason for doing this is to prevent showing the components part numbers to others for example when sending it for manufacturing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Details like this should be in the question instead of comments.  I have edited the question for you.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't send the PCBDoc file for manufacturing. You send the Gerbers and fab drawing for the PCB. Nothing in that data exposes any component information.
2. For assembly, you're either going to have to disclose the part numbers in the BOM, or kit it yourself, and go through a lot of unnecessary obfuscation.

If somebody wants to copy your widget they will. You can't stop them. To keep your data safest, use reputable vendors, and not some random sketchy CM in China.

Comment: I have a problem with Gerber files. My PCB maker doesn't work with Gerbers.I should to give them PCBDoc file.

Comment: Is it possible to make Gerber files then convert them to Altium PCB files?

Comment: @Rasool Find a new PCB fabricator. This one is bad.

Comment: I prefer to work with him for his quality and prices. So I am finding a solution.

Comment: There are limited fabricators around me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It is possible to convert pcb doc file to Gerber and then convert gerbers to pcb doc file. For converting Gerbers to pcb file you can use File/Import/Quick load menu. Please see the video links bellow
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKLwqtTj5fk